# Remove xmlns: attributes from <CASH_RECEIPT_LOG>

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have the below XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns3:Bonger xmlns:ns3="http://NEXSTEP.Schemas.Bonger" xmlns:ns2="http://NEXSTEP.Schemas.NexstepTypes">
  <ROUTE_RECORD>
    <ns2:SENDER Sender_code="BO_SERVER"/>
    <ns2:RECEIPIENT Receipient_code="MASTER"/>
    <ns2:MESSAGE_ID Type_name="Bonger" Version_number="1.0"/>
    <ns2:DATE Date_of_preparation="2019-05-07+02:00" Time_of_preparation="15:14:24"/>
    <ns2:OverAllStatus>NY</ns2:OverAllStatus>
  </ROUTE_RECORD>
  <MESSAGE_RECORD>
    <InsertChange>
      <Message>
        <ns2:MessageId>1</ns2:MessageId>
        <ns2:FirmaNr>0</ns2:FirmaNr>
        <ns2:Status>NY</ns2:Status>
        <ns2:OpprettetEndretSlettet>
          <ns2:OpprettetTidspunkt>2019-05-07+02:00</ns2:OpprettetTidspunkt>
          <ns2:OpprettetKl>15:13:14.636+02:00</ns2:OpprettetKl>
          <ns2:EndretTidspunkt>2019-05-07+02:00</ns2:EndretTidspunkt>
          <ns2:EndretKl>15:14:15.492+02:00</ns2:EndretKl>
          <ns2:EndretAv>ADMIN</ns2:EndretAv>
        </ns2:OpprettetEndretSlettet>
      </Message>
      <Bongnr>B01-110</Bongnr>
      <RegisterId>B01</RegisterId>
      <DokumentType>B</DokumentType>
      <DokumentNr>B01-110</DokumentNr>
      <Avdeling>0</Avdeling>
      <KundeNr>0</KundeNr>
      <VareLager>553</VareLager>
      <BetalingsBetingelse/>
      <Brukernavn>ADMIN</Brukernavn>
      <Ordrerabatt>0</Ordrerabatt>
      <OrdrerabattSum>0</OrdrerabattSum>
      <Selger>0</Selger>
      <Bonglinjer>
        <Bonglinje xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns3:Varelinje">
          <createdTime>2019-05-07T15:13:14.636+02:00</createdTime>
          <createdBy>ADMIN</createdBy>
          <changedBy>ADMIN</changedBy>
          <linjenr>10</linjenr>
          <varenr>54295197</varenr>
          <varetext>FURU 98X098 CUIMP K-VIRKE C24</varetext>
          <amount>20</amount>
          <enhetkode>LM</enhetkode>
          <salesPrice>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>77.0</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </salesPrice>
          <salesPriceExVat>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>61.600</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </salesPriceExVat>
          <originalSalesPriceExVat>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>61.6</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </originalSalesPriceExVat>
          <costPrice>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>0.00</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </costPrice>
          <costPriceExVat>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>0.0</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </costPriceExVat>
          <discount1>0.00</discount1>
          <discount2>0.00</discount2>
          <specialDiscount1>0.00</specialDiscount1>
          <specialDiscount2>0.00</specialDiscount2>
          <ordreDiscount>0.000000</ordreDiscount>
          <discountedPrice>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>77.0</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </discountedPrice>
          <discountedPriceExVat>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>61.60</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </discountedPriceExVat>
          <sumSalesPrice>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>1540.0</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </sumSalesPrice>
          <sumSalesPriceExVat>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>1232.00</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </sumSalesPriceExVat>
          <sumCostPrice>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>0.00</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </sumCostPrice>
          <sumCostPriceExVat>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>0.00</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </sumCostPriceExVat>
          <sumDiscountedPrice>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>1540.0</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </sumDiscountedPrice>
          <sumDiscountedPriceExVat>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>1232.0</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </sumDiscountedPriceExVat>
          <mvaKode>VHØY</mvaKode>
          <mvaSats>25.00</mvaSats>
          <kampanje/>
          <offlinePrice>false</offlinePrice>
        </Bonglinje>
      </Bonglinjer>
      <totalSum>
        <ns2:BelopFelt>1232.00</ns2:BelopFelt>
        <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
      </totalSum>
      <totalDiscountedSum>
        <ns2:BelopFelt>1232.00</ns2:BelopFelt>
        <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
      </totalDiscountedSum>
      <totalSumInkVat>
        <ns2:BelopFelt>1540.00</ns2:BelopFelt>
        <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
      </totalSumInkVat>
      <totalDiscountedSumInkVat>
        <ns2:BelopFelt>1540.0</ns2:BelopFelt>
        <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
      </totalDiscountedSumInkVat>
      <vat>
        <ns2:BelopFelt>308.0</ns2:BelopFelt>
        <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
        <percent>25.00</percent>
      </vat>
      <DepositumInnbetalt>
        <ns2:BelopFelt>0</ns2:BelopFelt>
        <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
      </DepositumInnbetalt>
      <DepositumFratrukket>
        <ns2:BelopFelt>0</ns2:BelopFelt>
        <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
      </DepositumFratrukket>
      <BetaltCash>
        <ns2:BelopFelt>1000</ns2:BelopFelt>
        <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
      </BetaltCash>
      <BetaltCard>
        <ns2:BelopFelt>700</ns2:BelopFelt>
        <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
      </BetaltCard>
      <EkstraUttak>
        <ns2:BelopFelt>0</ns2:BelopFelt>
        <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
      </EkstraUttak>
      <CardInfo>
        <KortBetaling>
          <sum>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>500</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </sum>
          <ref>003144474517</ref>
          <timepoint>2019-05-07T15:13:30.000+02:00</timepoint>
          <typeCode>1</typeCode>
        </KortBetaling>
        <KortBetaling>
          <sum>
            <ns2:BelopFelt>200</ns2:BelopFelt>
            <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
          </sum>
          <ref>003145474521</ref>
          <timepoint>2019-05-07T15:13:55.000+02:00</timepoint>
          <typeCode>1</typeCode>
        </KortBetaling>
      </CardInfo>
      <BetaltGiftcard>
        <ns2:BelopFelt>0</ns2:BelopFelt>
        <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
      </BetaltGiftcard>
      <MoneyBack>
        <ns2:BelopFelt>160</ns2:BelopFelt>
        <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
      </MoneyBack>
      <RoundingAmount>
        <ns2:BelopFelt>0.0</ns2:BelopFelt>
        <ns2:Valutakode>NOK</ns2:Valutakode>
      </RoundingAmount>
      <printDocument>
        <document>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</document>
        <mimetype>text/plain</mimetype>
      </printDocument>
    </InsertChange>
  </MESSAGE_RECORD>
</ns3:Bonger>
```

I have a XSL transformer written as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns3="http://NEXSTEP.Schemas.Bonger" xmlns:ns2="http://NEXSTEP.Schemas.NexstepTypes">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/ns3:Bonger">
        <CASH_RECEIPT_LOG xmlns:xsi="urn:ifsworld-com:schemas:receive_cash_receipt_pos" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <MSG_CONTRACT>
                <xsl:value-of select="MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange/Avdeling"/>
            </MSG_CONTRACT>
            <MSG_DATE>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange/Message/ns2:OpprettetEndretSlettet/ns2:OpprettetTidspunkt, ' ',MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange/Message/ns2:OpprettetEndretSlettet/ns2:OpprettetKl )"/>
            </MSG_DATE>
            <CASH_RECEIPTS>
                <CASH_RECEIPT>
                    <CASH_RECEIPT_NO>
                        <xsl:value-of select="MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange/Bongnr"/>
                    </CASH_RECEIPT_NO>
                    <CASH_RECEIPT_DATE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange/Message/ns2:OpprettetEndretSlettet/ns2:OpprettetTidspunkt, ' ',MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange/Message/ns2:OpprettetEndretSlettet/ns2:OpprettetKl )"/>
                    </CASH_RECEIPT_DATE>
                    <CONTRACT>
                        <xsl:value-of select="MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange/Avdeling"/>
                    </CONTRACT>
                    <WORKSTATION_ID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange/RegisterId"/>
                    </WORKSTATION_ID>
                    <EMPLOYEE_ID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange/Brukernavn"/>
                    </EMPLOYEE_ID>
                    <CASH_REGISTER_ID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange/RegisterId"/>
                    </CASH_REGISTER_ID>
                    <CREATE_DATE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange/Message/ns2:OpprettetEndretSlettet/ns2:OpprettetTidspunkt, ' ',MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange/Message/ns2:OpprettetEndretSlettet/ns2:OpprettetKl )"/>
                    </CREATE_DATE>
                    <LINES>
                        <xsl:for-each select="MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange">
                            <xsl:if test="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/sumDiscountedPrice/ns2:BelopFelt[string-length() > 0]">
                                <CASH_RECEIPT_LINE>
                                    <CASH_RECEIPT_LINE_NO>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/linjenr"/>
                                    </CASH_RECEIPT_LINE_NO>
                                    <INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>INVPARTSALE</INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>
                                    <EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>1000</EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>
                                    <REFERENCE>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/varenr"/>
                                    </REFERENCE>
                                    <REGULAR_AMOUNT>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/salesPriceExVat/ns2:BelopFelt"/>
                                    </REGULAR_AMOUNT>
                                    <ACTUAL_AMOUNT>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/discountedPriceExVat/ns2:BelopFelt"/>
                                    </ACTUAL_AMOUNT>
                                    <QUANTITY>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/amount"/>
                                    </QUANTITY>
                                    <TOTAL_AMOUNT>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/sumDiscountedPrice/ns2:BelopFelt"/>
                                    </TOTAL_AMOUNT>
                                    <CURRENCY_CODE>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/sumDiscountedPrice/ns2:Valutakode"/>
                                    </CURRENCY_CODE>
                                    <FREE_TEXT_1>
                                    </FREE_TEXT_1>
                                    <FREE_TEXT_3>
                                    </FREE_TEXT_3>
                                </CASH_RECEIPT_LINE>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/mvaKode[string-length() > 0]">
                                <CASH_RECEIPT_LINE>
                                    <CASH_RECEIPT_LINE_NO>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/linjenr"/>
                                    </CASH_RECEIPT_LINE_NO>
                                    <INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>VAT</INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>
                                    <EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>1</EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>
                                    <REFERENCE>N/A</REFERENCE>
                                    <REGULAR_AMOUNT>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/sumDiscountedPriceExVat/ns2:BelopFelt"/>
                                    </REGULAR_AMOUNT>
                                    <ACTUAL_AMOUNT>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/sumDiscountedPrice/ns2:BelopFelt - Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/sumDiscountedPriceExVat/ns2:BelopFelt"/>
                                    </ACTUAL_AMOUNT>
                                    <QUANTITY>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/amount"/>
                                    </QUANTITY>
                                    <TOTAL_AMOUNT>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/sumDiscountedPrice/ns2:BelopFelt - Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/sumDiscountedPriceExVat/ns2:BelopFelt"/>
                                    </TOTAL_AMOUNT>
                                    <CURRENCY_CODE>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/sumDiscountedPrice/ns2:Valutakode"/>
                                    </CURRENCY_CODE>
                                </CASH_RECEIPT_LINE>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="/ns3:Bonger/MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange/DokumentType != 'P' ">
                                <CASH_RECEIPT_LINE>
                                    <CASH_RECEIPT_LINE_NO></CASH_RECEIPT_LINE_NO>
                                    <INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>VAT</INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>
                                    <EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>1</EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>
                                    <REFERENCE>N/A</REFERENCE>
                                    <REGULAR_AMOUNT>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/sumDiscountedPriceExVat/ns2:BelopFelt"/>
                                    </REGULAR_AMOUNT>
                                    <ACTUAL_AMOUNT>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/sumDiscountedPrice/ns2:BelopFelt - Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/sumDiscountedPriceExVat/ns2:BelopFelt"/>
                                    </ACTUAL_AMOUNT>
                                    <QUANTITY>0</QUANTITY>
                                    <TOTAL_AMOUNT>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/sumDiscountedPrice/ns2:BelopFelt - Bonglinjer/Bonglinje/sumDiscountedPriceExVat/ns2:BelopFelt"/>
                                    </TOTAL_AMOUNT>
                                    <CURRENCY_CODE>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="BetaltCash/ns2:Valutakode"/>
                                    </CURRENCY_CODE>
                                </CASH_RECEIPT_LINE>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </LINES>
                </CASH_RECEIPT>
            </CASH_RECEIPTS>
        </CASH_RECEIPT_LOG>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My XML output after transformation is as below

```
<CASH_RECEIPT_LOG xmlns:xsi="urn:test-com:schemas:receive_cash_receipt_pos"
                  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                  xmlns:ns3="http://NEXSTEP.Schemas.Bonger"
                  xmlns:ns2="http://NEXSTEP.Schemas.NexstepTypes">
   <MSG_CONTRACT>0</MSG_CONTRACT>
   <MSG_DATE>2019-05-07+02:00 15:13:14.636+02:00</MSG_DATE>
   <CASH_RECEIPTS>
      <CASH_RECEIPT>
         <CASH_RECEIPT_NO>B01-110</CASH_RECEIPT_NO>
         <CASH_RECEIPT_DATE>2019-05-07+02:00 15:13:14.636+02:00</CASH_RECEIPT_DATE>
         <CONTRACT>0</CONTRACT>
         <WORKSTATION_ID>B01</WORKSTATION_ID>
         <EMPLOYEE_ID>ADMIN</EMPLOYEE_ID>
         <CASH_REGISTER_ID>B01</CASH_REGISTER_ID>
         <CREATE_DATE>2019-05-07+02:00 15:13:14.636+02:00</CREATE_DATE>
         <LINES>
            <CASH_RECEIPT_LINE>
               <CASH_RECEIPT_LINE_NO>10</CASH_RECEIPT_LINE_NO>
               <INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>INVPARTSALE</INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>
               <EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>1000</EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>
               <REFERENCE>54295197</REFERENCE>
               <REGULAR_AMOUNT>61.600</REGULAR_AMOUNT>
               <ACTUAL_AMOUNT>61.60</ACTUAL_AMOUNT>
               <QUANTITY>20</QUANTITY>
               <TOTAL_AMOUNT>1540.0</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
               <CURRENCY_CODE>NOK</CURRENCY_CODE>
               <FREE_TEXT_1/>
               <FREE_TEXT_3/>
            </CASH_RECEIPT_LINE>
            <CASH_RECEIPT_LINE>
               <CASH_RECEIPT_LINE_NO>10</CASH_RECEIPT_LINE_NO>
               <INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>VAT</INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>
               <EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>1</EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>
               <REFERENCE>N/A</REFERENCE>
               <REGULAR_AMOUNT>1232.0</REGULAR_AMOUNT>
               <ACTUAL_AMOUNT>308</ACTUAL_AMOUNT>
               <QUANTITY>20</QUANTITY>
               <TOTAL_AMOUNT>308</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
               <CURRENCY_CODE>NOK</CURRENCY_CODE>
            </CASH_RECEIPT_LINE>
            <CASH_RECEIPT_LINE>
               <CASH_RECEIPT_LINE_NO/>
               <INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>VAT</INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>
               <EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>1</EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>
               <REFERENCE>N/A</REFERENCE>
               <REGULAR_AMOUNT>1232.0</REGULAR_AMOUNT>
               <ACTUAL_AMOUNT>308</ACTUAL_AMOUNT>
               <QUANTITY>0</QUANTITY>
               <TOTAL_AMOUNT>308</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
               <CURRENCY_CODE>NOK</CURRENCY_CODE>
            </CASH_RECEIPT_LINE>
         </LINES>
      </CASH_RECEIPT>
   </CASH_RECEIPTS>
</CASH_RECEIPT_LOG>
```

Is there any way that I could remove the all the xmlns attributes from the <CASH_RECEIPT_LOG>

```
<CASH_RECEIPT_LOG xmlns:xsi="urn:test-com:schemas:receive_cash_receipt_pos"
                  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                  xmlns:ns3="http://NEXSTEP.Schemas.Bonger"
                  xmlns:ns2="http://NEXSTEP.Schemas.NexstepTypes">
```

final output should be like

<CASH_RECEIPT_LOG>...<CASH_RECEIPT_LOG>

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Unused namespace declarations should have no effect on the *information content* of the XML, which is what tooling based around actual XML should care about.

Comment: Next time, please post a [mcve], not 187 + 123 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, these are not *attributes* but *namespace declarations*.

Next, they are put there by your own stylesheet - so if you don't want them, change this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns3="http://NEXSTEP.Schemas.Bonger" xmlns:ns2="http://NEXSTEP.Schemas.NexstepTypes">
```

to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns3="http://NEXSTEP.Schemas.Bonger" xmlns:ns2="http://NEXSTEP.Schemas.NexstepTypes"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns2 ns3">
```

and this:

```
    <CASH_RECEIPT_LOG xmlns:xsi="urn:ifsworld-com:schemas:receive_cash_receipt_pos" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
```

to:

```
    <CASH_RECEIPT_LOG>
```